# How to cogroup three RDDs?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

## I have 3 RDD with similar partition key (let's say a String for the idOwner) :

```
JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Iterable<Cat>> rddCat
JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Iterable<Dog>> rddDog
JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Iterable<Fish>> rddFish
```

## How to go to the expected solution :

```
JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Tuple3<Iterable<Cat>, Iterable<Dog>, Iterable<fish>>>
```

I only manage to do this,

## Fail 1 :

```
rddCat.cogroup(rddDog, rddFish)
--> FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<PartitionKey, Tuple3<Iterable<Iterable<Cat>>, Iterable<Iterable<Dog>>, Iterable<Iterable<Fish>>>>
```

## Fail 2 :

```
JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Tuple2<Iterable<Cat>, Iterable<Dog>>> catDogRdd = rddCat.join(rddDog);
JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Tuple2<Tuple2<Iterable<Cat>, Iterable<Dog>>, Iterable<Fish>>> finalRdd = catDogRdd.join(rddFish);
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Use `join`, i.e. `def join[W](other: RDD[(K, W)]): RDD[(K, (V, W))]`).

I use Scala and the following seemed to work fine.

```
scala> r2.collect
res7: Array[(Int, Iterable[Int])] = Array((0,CompactBuffer(0, 1)), (3,CompactBuffer(6, 7)), (4,CompactBuffer(8, 9)), (1,CompactBuffer(2, 3)), (2,CompactBuffer(4, 5)))

scala> r3.collect
res8: Array[(Int, Iterable[Int])] = Array((0,CompactBuffer(0, 1, 2)), (3,CompactBuffer(9)), (1,CompactBuffer(3, 4, 5)), (2,CompactBuffer(6, 7, 8)))

scala> r5.collect
res9: Array[(Int, Iterable[Int])] = Array((0,CompactBuffer(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)), (1,CompactBuffer(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)))

scala> r2 join r3 join r5 collect
res10: Array[(Int, ((Iterable[Int], Iterable[Int]), Iterable[Int]))] = Array((0,((CompactBuffer(0, 1),CompactBuffer(0, 1, 2)),CompactBuffer(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))), (1,((CompactBuffer(2, 3),CompactBuffer(3, 4, 5)),CompactBuffer(5, 6, 7, 8, 9))))
```

Consult [org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions).

Comment: Thank you but If I use join I only manage to have : `JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Tuple2<Iterable<Cat>, Iterable<Dog>>> catDogRdd =
 rddCat.join(rddDog);` and then `JavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, Tuple2<Tuple2<Iterable<Cat>, Iterable<Dog>>, Iterable<Fish>>> finalRdd =
 catDogRdd.join(rddFish);`

Comment: @Reactormonk I expected tuple3, not tuple2 in antoher tuple2

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with a little help of Guava:

```
    //given
    final JavaPairRDD<Character, Iterable<Integer>> rdd1 = ...
    final JavaPairRDD<Character, Iterable<Integer>> rdd2 = ...
    final JavaPairRDD<Character, Iterable<Integer>> rdd3 = ...

    // when
    final JavaPairRDD<Character, Tuple3<Iterable<Iterable<Integer>>, Iterable<Iterable<Integer>>, Iterable<Iterable<Integer>>>> grouped = rdd1.cogroup(rdd2, rdd3);
    final JavaPairRDD<Character, Tuple3<Iterable<Integer>, Iterable<Integer>, Iterable<Integer>>> flattened = grouped.mapValues(
            t3 -> new Tuple3<>(Iterables.concat(t3._1()), Iterables.concat(t3._2()), Iterables.concat(t3._3()))
    );
```

I wonder @Fundhor how You managed to yield this signature in Your first attempt. It doesn't seem possible.